# Spring boot REST API application doesn't see OAuth2 libraries

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I want to secure my REST API with authentication using OAuth2, but on beginning of my journey i faced some problems like `"Cannot resolve symbol 'AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter'"` didn't find any solution on the internet so i asking you. I simply cannot import it and with i write something like  `import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;` it says that in cannot resolve oauth2.

My pom.xml file is look's like:

```
<groupId>com.bsuir</groupId>
<artifactId>buspark</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>buspark</name>
<description>labs</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--SECURITY-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth2</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--SECURITY-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--SWAGGER-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--SWAGGER-->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `mvn dependency:resolve` ?

Answer (score 1):

Group id contains an error. It must be oauth without 2. The final version looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this dependency wouldn't work without a version for me, once I added it, it was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded libraries (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/oauth/spring-security-oauth2/2.3.0.RELEASE/) manually and installed them in "Project Setting" -> "Libraries"

Comment: This is a temporary workaround at best. It looks like your groupId in the Pom was incorrect.